# Indenting function braces in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, autoformatting, autoformat

I am working on a C++ project and using Eclipse as the IDE. The coding standards for the project specify indenting the initial and closing braces for a function, as in:

```
int main()
  {
  return 0;
  }
```

Is there an option in Eclipse 4.3.1 to automatically indent this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the main menu to Navigate to Window->Preferences.

On the resulting dialog, expand your way to C/C++->Code Style->Formatter. Set Active Profile to Whitesmiths and edit to taste.

[image]

For example, it looks like you want to set Indentation size and Tab size on the Indentation tab to 2.

[image]